# Symfony 1.4 embedRelation Integrity constraint violation

Tags: forms, symfony1, doctrine

I have found some useful info on this issue but can't quite wrap my head around the solutions. So I'm hoping someone can explain to me a helpful solution and not a plugin/hack/workaround I'm trying very hard to do the "Right" way:

So here is what my issue:

schema:

```
detect_relations: true    
Student:
  tableName: student
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: ''
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    parents_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: ''
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
   relations:
     Parents:
      refClass: StudentParentLink
      local: student_id
      foreign: parents_id
      onDelete: CASCADE
Parents:
  tableName: parents
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: ''
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    email_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '0'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    relations:
      Student:
        refClass: StudetParentLink
        local: parents_id
        forign: student_id
        onDelete: CASCADE
Email:
  tableName: email
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    email:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: ''
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
StudentParentLink:
  tableName: student_parent_link
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    student_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '0'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    parents_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '0'
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
```

So in english, I have a student who has a parent(s) and that parent(s) has an email address, simple enough.

So in my Student Form I have the following:

```
 //studentForm.class.php
 public function configure()
 {
     if($this->getObject()->isNew() || count($this->getObject()->Parents) == 0)
     {
         $this->getObject()->Parents[] = new Parents();
     }

     $parentsSubForm = new sfForm();
     $i = 1;
     foreach($this->getObject()->Parents as $parents)
     {
       $parentsForm = new ParentsForm($parents);
       $parentSubForm->embedForm("Parent $i",$parentsForm);
       $i++;
     }
  $this->embedForm('Parents',$parentSubForm)
 }
```

This looks as expected and works for adding a Student record, however on update I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2' for key 1
```

I'm not sure what is happening only that it looks like it's doing an insert not update for the parent, is that as designed? I just need to be able to add/edit the parents email (and all other data points not listed in this example for simplicity) via the Student Form

As always any direction or comments are very welcome! I am just getting the hang of Symfony and little nuances like this are great to learn so I can move forward!

~ Mahalo Zjoia

**UPDATE**

So I am desperate here and totally confused, I've tried everything I can think of and find and yes I am able to get the error to go away but what is ambiguous in the above schema is EMAIL is Many-to-One so doing things as described in Advance Forms doesn't work you need to relate it different so I have the following Code:

```
 if($this->getObject()->isNew() || count($this->getObject()->Email) < 1)
 {
    $email = new Email($this->getObject()->Email);
    $emailForm = new EmailForm($email);
    $this->embedForm('Parents Email', $emailForm);
    $useFields[] = 'Parents Email';
 }else{
    $this->embedRelation('Email');
    $this->widgetSchema['Email']->setLabel('Parents Email');
    $useFields[] = 'Email';
 }
```

This works just fine if I am in the Parent Form but when I am in the Student Form (which embeds the parents form) it's not relating the email back to the parent, it creates the Email correctly in the `email table` but does not insert the email_id in the `parent table`

I'm going mad with this I just don't understand, please help!

**IDIOT**

**ANSWER**

Turns out I had some old models that were linking tables that I thought a model rebuild would remove turns out not so much, got that removed and all the crazy weirdness is gone, things work perfect!

Always something stupid that is missed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is very common and described at the symfony website.
[Here](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms) is example of what you need.

Also may be useful this [documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_4/en/). "Especially Chapter 11 - Doctrine Integration".

Regards
Evgeny

Comment: Check Updated info...still need some help!